# Trying to find the terminal object (and category) for this universal property

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

Consider an index set $I = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.
Let $V$ be a vector space and $v_I$ be a basis that is,
$\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$. Let $\phi: I \rightarrow V$ be a map
that maps the index set to a basis vector
$i \xrightarrow[]{\phi} v_i$.
Let $W$ be another $n-$dimensional vector space and
$f: I \rightarrow W$ be any map. Then we have the following
commutative diagram:

[image: Commutative diagram]

This looks like a universal property since: for all $W$ and $f$, there exists a unique linear
transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$.
This is true since $T$ is specified by where the basis elements
$v_i$ go into $W$.

Now my question: if there is a universal property, there needs to be a certain category and a certain terminal object. What are these in this case?

It seems like the morphism $\phi$ (or really the pair $(I,\phi)$ is the initial object in a
category where the objects are morphisms in the ambient diagram and morphisms are the commutative diagrams.

If the ambient category is $\text{Vect}$ where $V,W$ are objects but $I$ is not... I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a universal property, and we can indeed find a category where $(V, \phi)$ is initial.

The category that you're looking for is a certain kind of comma category.

Here's a direct definition.

Objects are pairs $(U, g)$, where $U$ is a vector space and $g$ is an ordinary function $g : I \to U$.

An arrow from $(U, g)$ to $(W, h)$ is a linear map $T : U \to W$ wuch that $h = T \circ g$.

Composition is just ordinary composition of functions. It's easy to verify the axioms of a category from here.

Then we see that the claim "$V$ is the free vector space on $I$" is simply stating that $(V, \phi)$ is the initial object.

This is related to notions of the representability of a functor and of adjoints.

Edit: if you insist that a universal property be stated in terms of a terminal object, just take the opposite category of the one I have described, which makes $(V, \phi)$ into a terminal object.

Comment: And if the OP insists that a universal property should always be interpreted as a *terminal* object in a certain category (this is a silly convention, but it seems to be implicit in the question), you can just consider the opposite of the category you described in your answer.

Comment: Thanks.. got it.. very helpful..  just for clarity I used terminal to mean either initial or final.. but was useful to help with the notion of the opposite category.

Comment: @MathDilettante Terminal object and final object are synonyms. If you use the word terminal to describe an initial object, you'll just confuse people.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I see that now.. thx